# Use contentProvider and RecycleView?

Tags: android

I have viewPager and about 7 pages in it. Almost all pages has list of data. Data I get from sqlite db. I use `ContentProvider` and `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>` for updating data after sql data was changed (aka `getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null)`). It works, but I replaced ListView to RecycleView because it seems more flexible and I had some problem with listView, but one problem it doesn't have default cursor adapter. I found one in github but and now it works following way:

ContentProvider has methods `update`, `insert`, `query`, `delete`. In one page of view pagers I do `getActivity().getContentResolver().update(....);` or others method and in other pages data auto update using `LoaderManager`(The usual approach as for me).

But now I doubt:
Need I content provider or not? `ContentProvider` provides of data to third-party applications but not for own app and it is overhead.
Maybe `RecyclerView` has other features for updating data and my approach is not good?

Comment: if you already have a `ContentProvider` then use it with https://gist.github.com/Shywim/127f207e7248fe48400b or https://github.com/blandware/android-atleap/blob/master/atleap-core/src/main/java/com/blandware/android/atleap/loader/SimpleCursorRecyclerAdapter.java

Comment: thanks, but i already use adapter for recycle view, my question about - is it good approach use ContentProvider in my case? I updated my questions.

Comment: your approach is good,  no worries...

Answer (score 0):

I think better way it's use CursorLoader. Becouse it hangs observer on cursor, and if you add new data you can use `getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);` so CusrorLoader will get new cursor with fresh data automatically and you can just use swap for update RecyclerView(but RecyclerView dostn't have default implemenation adapter with cursor, so you will need find something like it [RecyclerViewCursorAdapter](https://gitlab.com/snippets/16978)).

Comment: this particular implementation is a bit "poor" in features: see my comment above for better ones (the second link provides a "SimpleCursorAdapter" like adapter which is very handy in use

Comment: thanks, I already use CursorAdapter for recyclerView. My question about is it good approach or it is  overhead, and better manually do updating data and not use ``` getActivity().getContentResolver().update(...) ```

Comment: pskink, those adapters is good, but approach that I described I is the easiest. comalex3, you can just add Contact class for bigger flexibility with ContentProvider

Comment: i mean your adapter implementation has no useful features like FilterQueryProvider, CursorFilter etc

Comment: i know, but in most cases it unnecessary

Comment: in most cases (more than 9/10) [this](https://github.com/blandware/android-atleap/blob/master/atleap-core/src/main/java/com/blandware/android/atleap/loader/SimpleCursorRecyclerAdapter.java) adapter can be used with absolutely **NO** more other code except creating the adapter instance (just like "normal" `SimpleCursorAdapter`)